# Derive 4 specific size integers from a string

Tags: math, lua, cryptography

I need to generate 4: 6, 7, 44, and 8 bit integers for a cipher project I'm working on.
How would I go on about doing this in lua as a cryptographically secure function?

What I've tried:

```
-- derive secret from the whole string
-- 6-bit integer = byte % 64
-- 7-bit integer = byte % 128
-- 44-bit integer = byte % 17592186044416
-- 8-bit integer = byte % 256
local secret = { 2, 2, 2, 2 }

for i = 1, #str do
    local _byte = byte(str, i)
    secret[1] = (secret[1] * _byte + 1) % 64
    secret[2] = (secret[2] * _byte + 1) % 128
    secret[3] = (secret[3] * _byte + 1) % 17592186044416
    secret[4] = (secret[4] * _byte + 1) % 256
end
return secret
```

I am pretty sure what I have isn't cryptographically secure nor reliable

This is what my random secret function does, it generates usable integers, but it doesn't derive them from a string:

```
local secret = {
        random:NextNumber(0, 63), --// 6-bit  arbitrary integer (0..63)
        random:NextNumber(0, 127), --// 7-bit  arbitrary integer (0..127)
        random:NextNumber(0, 17592186044415), --// 44-bit arbitrary integer (0..17592186044415)
        random:NextNumber(0, 255); --// 8-bit  arbitrary integer (0..255)
    };
```

Comment: Just calculate any hash-function on your string (for example, MD5, SHA-1, SHA256, there exist a lot of Lua libraries to calculate hash-sums).  Then split the hashsum result (hexadecimal string) into 12-hex-digit chunks, convert them to numbers (up to 2^48) and apply Lua modulo operator to reduce to the size you need.

Comment: MD5 is no longer secure. Better to use a more recent hash function such as SHA256 or SHA-3.

Comment: Thank you! I am getting decent results by dividing the string in 10 letter partitions, and converting those to hex and using the modulo operator with the integer sizes I need. I guess it works now https://imgur.com/a/1XWFai5

Comment: Are we talking homework project, or are we talking _actual_ "cryptographically secure" function for a personal project that you intend to actually _use_? Because it doesn't matter what you come up with: 44 bits is not secure. If this is homework, the top comment is a decent idea, if it's not: don't roll your own, use an off-the-shelf, known secure, well tested encryption library =)